# Ограничение на количество запросов к API VK

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте!

Есть на странице запрос к апи.
Стоит ограничение на 5 запросов в секунду от ВК.

Если юзер сталкнётся с ошибкой, что максимальное превышено количество запросов за одну секунду к этому приложению, то срабатывает через 2 секунды редирект на этот же скрипт, и запрос выполняется заного.

Вот меня интересует одна штука, что если запрос выполнят сразу например 100 юзеров. Что тогда будет?

По логике все они через 2 секунды редиректом отправятся повторять запрос.

И вот мне интересно, 5 человек из ста всё же выполнят запрос? Дальше должно остаться 95 людей, потом ещё через 2 секунды 5 человек выполнят запрос, и так далее.

Или же никто из этих 100 человек не выполнят запрос повторно и они все опять через 2 секунды пойдут на запрос. и так до бесконечности?

Comment: Почему же не выполнят? 5 из 100, если каждый делает по одному вызову.

Comment: Может рандомно число определять? от 1 до 5 сек. У каждого человека по разному обновится, возможно так распределится нагрузка? и в разно время все выполнят запросы, ну и быстрее всё протечёт?

Comment: Как минимум не могут 100 юзеров нажать одновременно кнопку.. отставания в доли секунды, но будет. А также время запроса может быть у всех разное - в зависимости от скорости соединения, а также на сколько быстро загружается запросами сервак контакта... то есть даже если все нажмут точно одновременно, то ответ всем придет неодновременно... поэтому кто-то после первого сообщения да опередит всех

Comment: Не стоит заниматься такими расчетами, все зависит не от вас.